# android run class in service with new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i just use service to make something like chathead and this is my result

[image]

but only i have two problem

first some time my service killed i notice that's on weak device so how can i prevent it from killed in same time the facebook messenger never killed

second my class animation not smooth i think i must run the class on new thread

`xxx = new classanimation (mContext);`

i tried this

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            xxx = new classanimation (mContext);

        }
    });
```

but i see it same no different

and this is my service code

```
public class MyCustomService extends Service   {


private volatile HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
private static Context mContext;
Handler mHandler;
IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
public static Socket client;
public classanimation xxx;




@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public MyCustomService getServerInstance() {
        return MyCustomService.this;
    }
}

 private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    // Define how to handle any incoming messages here
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // ...
        // When needed, stop the service with
        // stopSelf();
    }
}


public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.mContext = this;

    xxx= new classanimation(mContext); //class i run it but its not smooth

    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());


    // An Android handler thread internally operates on a looper.
    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyCustomService.HandlerThread");

    mHandlerThread.start();
    // An Android service handler is a handler running on a specific background thread.
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Send empty message to background thread
    mServiceHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 500);
    // or run code in background
    mServiceHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something here in background!
            SessionManager session = new SessionManager(mContext);



            // If desired, stop the service
            //stopSelf();
        }
    });
    // Keep service around "sticky"
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Cleanup service before destruction
    mHandlerThread.quit();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that your service is never killed, you can make your service a foreground service by using a notifiaction. This means that there will always be a notification icon when the service is running, but it will never be killed. For example :

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text), System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title), getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: thanks for response i will try that's :) still the smooth animation problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent from killing,Yes but you can minimize probability of killing by starting service in different process than your app process.

Comment: You i agree with ak0692. You are using main Looper, you should different process.  Sample code.

   HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("MyCustomService ", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();
      Now use this thread.getLooper() for handler.

Comment: thanks i will try that's too :)  still animation class not smooth problem